# How to trade stock e.g, BABA using monthly options (wheel strategy)?

Tags: options, put-options, covered-call, covered-call-writing

Say you want to buy up to 400 shares of BABA in the current $130 range to $100. How do you implement an option strategy in the meantime to make some extra cash while waiting for a $10 stock gain?

Buy 100 shares@$130, sell 1 monthly call contract@$140
& sell 1 monthly put contract @$120.

Price drops below $120, now you have 200 shares@ $125 avg.
Now sell 2 monthly call contracts @$135 & sell 1 monthly put contract @$110.

Repeat until price drop to $100.

Is there a more efficient monthly income option strategy?

Answer (score 0):

A covered call is synthetically equivalent to a short put so your strategy of buying 100 shares, selling a $140 covered call and selling a $120 put is the same as selling a $140 put and selling a $120 put.  Why do 3 trades with more slippage and commissions when you can do only two?

Both positions have an asymmetric risk/reward profile (R/R) because they're long delta - you have the potential for a modest gain while bearing all of the downside risk.  AFAIC, this is fine if it's a stock that you want to own at the net price but as for efficiency, not so much.

Averaging down by taking on another short put is fine if you're building a position that you want to own.  It's a bad idea if you're doing it because you have 'breakevenitis'.  A problematic stock with increasing exposure is a bad recipe.

Is there a more efficient monthly income option strategy?  That depends on how you define efficient.  In my world, that means a better R/R ratio and that translates into vertical spreads.  Yes, less profit per trade but no catastrophes where share price has dropped so much that the only way to get a decent covered call premium would be to write many months out (you've married the stock) or you sell a lower strike that locks in a loss should the stock reverse and moon.

There are a number of other strategies with better R/R profile but they tend to give up the immediate income in return for risk management.

Last comment:  Last year was unprecedented.  Lots of stimulus cash fueled the up move.  Long delta strategies did well.  Should the market head south, you'll be averaging down a lot of positions and hoping for a short recovery as in 2020.  However, if it's 18 months as in 2000 and 2008, rut roh.  Give some thought to the risk management side of the equation.

Comment: Thank you for the great advice. What is a strategy with a balance of better R/R profile with some income besides vertical spread?

Comment: A better R/R profile means less long delta which is accomplished with spreads (vertical, iron condor, Jade Lizard, Seagull, etc.). The tradeoff is less income for more protection.